# What is the difference between DateGreaterThanEqual and DateIsGreaterThanEqual in JPA Repository?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to get all the Reservations for a user with username that are after the current date or equal the current date

Do I need to use:

```
List<Reservation> findReservationsByUsernameAndDateGreaterThanEqual(String username, Date date);
```

OR

```
List<Reservation> findReservationsByUsernameAndDateIsGreaterThanEqual(String username, Date date);
```

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is literally the `Is` part. Functionally they are the same.

You can find this information in https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords

Or if you prefer the [source code you should take a look at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.Type](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/1f1c34b4238f74263d02169a8b71b612c2e4e16b/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/query/parser/Part.java#L175)

Comment: Oh okey it is really that simple! Thank you!